# How to overload __next__ inside __init__?

Tags: python, overloading, magic-methods

I am writing range generator. Depending on whether the step is positive or negative, `__next__` should compare `start` and `end` with `<=` or `>=`. I would like to check if `step` is positive once, and define `__next__` depending on that comparison. This is what I did (to simplify, allow only exactly three inputs):

```
class MyRange:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.min, self.max, self.step = args[0] - args[2], args[1], args[2]

        if self.step > 0:
            self.__next__ = self.next_pos
        else:
            self.__next__ = self.next_neg

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        pass
    
    def next_pos(self):
        self.min += self.step
        if self.min >= self.max:
            raise StopIteration
        return self.min

    def next_neg(self):
        self.min += self.step
        if self.min <= self.max:
            raise StopIteration
        return self.min
```

If `__next__` is not defined outside of `__init__`, then I get an error:
`TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'MyRange'`.

I assumed that defining it as above would first initialise it according to the `def __next__(self)`, and then overwrite in `__init__`, but the order is the opposite. Why is it not being overloaded? How can I overwrite `__next__` depending on the `step` when creating an instance?

---

I know that I could store `next_pos` or `next_neg` inside `self.my_comparison`, and define

```
    def __next__(self):
        return self.my_comparison()
```

but I am wondering how I can overload `__next__` inside `__init__` and why it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: You don't really override methods by making them instance attributes... you *shadow* them on the instance*. In the case of magic methods, you cannot even shadow them, because they are looked up directly on the class. Just choose a different design.

Comment: Another way to implement this would be with two subclasses: `MyRange_Pos` and `MyRange_Neg`, and make `MyRange()` a factory function.

Comment: I assume the reason for the original TypeError is because standard iteration methods (e.g. `iter()`) check the class dictionary to see if it contains `__next__`, rather than the class instance.

Comment: One *simple* difference you could make is instead of trying to shadow all of `__next__` just make it depend on a `if self.predicate(self): raise StopIteration`, and then assign `self.predicate = lambda self: self.min <= self.max` etc it seems you already aknowledged you can do that sort of thing

Answer (score 1):

Python dunder (or magic) methods are always looked on the *class*  of an object, and never picked from the instance. Assigning an ordinary function to an instance that will work as a method will work, although it won't get the `self` argument injected by the Python runtime - but dunder methods are called by the runtime itself, and they are picked from the appropriate class slot for each functionality.

That is easy to work around: you can use your class defined `__next__` method to call another, instance bound callable, as an ordinary, "user side" call. You can then make this binding in `__init__` as you had devised:

```
class MyRange:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.min, self.max, self.step = args[0] - args[2], args[1], args[2]

        if self.step > 0:
            self._user_next = self.next_pos
        else:
            self._user_next = self.next_neg

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        return self._user_next()
    
    def next_pos(self):
        ...

    def next_neg(self):
        ...
```

Note that I wrote above that callables bound to the instance in this way won't get "self" injected by Python - however, this code is not assigining an ordinary function there: when we write `self.user_method = self.method` - the `self.method` part creates a "bound method" - a callable that will already insert the `self` to the underlying function (unbound method) when called. And that bound method is then assigned as a common instance attribute. When we execute `self.usermethod()`, first `usermethod` is retrieved from the instance, with no transformation mechanism (such as `self` arg injection) and then called.